# Bootstrap datetimepicker default date&time in expanded calendar only

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

This configuration:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: moment(),
        sideBySide: true
        });
});
```

allows set default date & time when no value is set for this field (e.g. from database).

**My question**: I would like to configure it so it should show default date&time only after clicking on calendar icon. I.e. if no value is passed to the input it should be empty by default, and if user clicks on calendar, it becomes default (see explanation picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/426#issuecomment-176517522):

```
$("#myDateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.show', function() {
  return $(this).data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(new Date());
});
```

It isn't very elegant, so if somebody knows how to make it more pretty, your answers are welcome.